# jwplayer().setConfig() is not exist

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

In the official reference of jwplayer, at the very beginning there is a function named setConfig:

jwplayer().setConfig()

https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/javascript-api-reference/

This function doesn't exist at all in the jwplayer instance. I have tried to change some configuration like this:

```
player.setConfig([{
    autostart: 'viewable',
    mute: false,
    volume: 25
}]);
```

but the browser throws me the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: player.setConfig is not a function**

I am also googling this but in vein. So anyone knows how to change those configurations after the video is already loaded in other words after the jwplayer has been initialized?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have also tried 
jwplayer("videoItem_1").setConfig({...}); but the same error happens

Answer (score 0):

`.setConfig` should only be called when the player has already been initialised, if you're calling this as the player is being initialised you should use:

```
jwplayer("myDiv").setup({
    "file": "http://example.com/myVideo.mp4",
    "image": "http://example.com/myImage.png",
    "height": 360,
    "width": 640
});
```

Comment: That is what I am doing. I am using setConfig after player is initialized. And the result is that error that I have mentioned...

Comment: It's very strange, I made a simple example at jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/nmcobalt/Lh5qb0jg/
and works like a charm! So I have to figure out what's wrong to my first implementation.

Comment: Missing dependency on a file perhaps?

Comment: No, the video is playing normaly. But when I call the setConfig function it throws that error... One thing to note is that the jwplayer I have installed on the problematic video is premium. It is not the same jwplayer I used in the fiddle... And there is no console warning or error that warns about a missing dependency...

Comment: In your fiddle you're calling .setup, but your issue is with .setConfig, correct? Rule out the other problem by switching to the regular version of JWPlayer, but I doubt thats an issue. Out of interest, why do you need to alter the config after init?

Comment: Simple thing you may have overlooked - make sure the problem embed is actually using JW player version 7.12 or higher.

Comment: I change setConfig after setup on browser resize because the site is responsive and I want in desktop viewport the player to autostart and at mobile not.

Comment: Having trawled the docs on this I found this comment on the official support channel https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/9481763-changing-configuration-options-after-setup- then reviewing the current documentation it appears that method isn't available (https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/configuration-reference/). I would check that your current version actually supports the method

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my current jwplayer version (7.11). When I updated to the next version (as jherrieven mentioned); the problem solved!
So thanks all for your help!